# Why is the reference for ConfigurationErrorsException missing from my .Net 3.0 application?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, error-handling, .net-3.0

I have a .NET 3.0 Winform Application with a corrupt user.config file causing system config errors.

I wanted to improve handle these errors, similar to how it's done in [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30216/Handling-Corrupt-user-config-Settings) on CodeProject.

To use '

However, when I try and use the 'ConfigurationErrorsException' to get the name of corrupted file I receive the following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'ConfigurationErrorsException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have only seen this error previously where there were .NET framework conflicts.
The project has the target framework .NET 3.0. The `ConfigurationErrorsException` was [added in 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationerrorsexception(v=vs.80).aspx), so I didn't think there would be a framework conflict there.

The version 3.0 documentation is lacking compared to other versions and does say:

> [The current value is not one of the EnableSessionState values.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationerrorsexception(v=vs.85).aspx)

Which I'm not entirely sure what that implies (the documentation for [EnableSessionState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.enablesessionstate(v=vs.85).aspx) lead to more confusion rather than less).

- **Why does the program fail to build, with a type or namespace missing error?**
- **Is this related to targeting .NET 3.0?**
- If so, **Is there an alternative for .NET 3.0?**

**EDIT:**
I have made sure to include 'using System.Configuration' at the top of my page. The total list of usings is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Linq;
//using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using ProjectName.Properties;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

Comment: Your project needs to reference `System.Configuration.dll` and you need to have `using System.Configuration` at the top of your code file since you aren't specifying the namespace,

Comment: @DStanley - I have included the System.Configuration using at the top of the code - I edited the question to clarify this. I haven't actually confirmed the .dll is in the references so will double check that now.

Comment: In what way is the `user.Config` corrupt?  Could it be breaking the project's reference to `system.Configuration`?

Comment: the _project_ needs to have a reference to `system.Configuration` as well.

Comment: @DStanley - you are correct, I had forgotten to tick system.Configuration in the references part of my project in MVS